# SOAP deploy: "Entity is null or entity element's name is null" for few searchSettingsByObject in Search.settings

Tags: soap-api, deployment, soap, search

[image: Salesforce deployment error searchSettingsByObject]

We do not understand why we facing with this problem.

Full **Search.settings**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SearchSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <documentContentSearchEnabled>true</documentContentSearchEnabled>
    <optimizeSearchForCJKEnabled>false</optimizeSearchForCJKEnabled>
    <recentlyViewedUsersForBlankLookupEnabled>true</recentlyViewedUsersForBlankLookupEnabled>
    <searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Account</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Activity</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Asset</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Attachment</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Campaign</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Case</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>CaseComment</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>CollaborationGroup</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Contact</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>ContentVersion</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Contract</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>DandBCompany</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Document</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Idea</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Lead</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Macro</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Note</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Opportunity</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Order</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Pricebook2</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>PricebookEntry</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Product2</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Question</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Report</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>Solution</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>User</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__A_Silin_Raman_4__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Api_Rename_Raman__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Api_Rename_Silin__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__DFSS_Permissions__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__DFSS_SnapShot_Item__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__DFSS_SnapShot_Job_List__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__DFSS_SnapShot_Push__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Estimate_Lines__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Estimate__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Invoice_Line_Items__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Invoice__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Milestones__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_A1__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_A2__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_A3__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_A4__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_B1__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_B2__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_B3__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_B4__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Object_B5__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Projects__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Raman_Child__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Raman_Object__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__TT1__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Team_Member__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Team__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__TestBatch__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Test__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Time_Spent_on_Tasks__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__Timesheets__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__myobj_3__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
        <searchSettingsByObject>
            <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled>
            <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>
            <name>wave16__test_rollback__c</name>
            <resultsPerPageCount>0</resultsPerPageCount>
        </searchSettingsByObject>
    </searchSettingsByObject>
    <sidebarAutoCompleteEnabled>true</sidebarAutoCompleteEnabled>
    <sidebarDropDownListEnabled>true</sidebarDropDownListEnabled>
    <sidebarLimitToItemsIOwnCheckboxEnabled>true</sidebarLimitToItemsIOwnCheckboxEnabled>
    <singleSearchResultShortcutEnabled>true</singleSearchResultShortcutEnabled>
    <spellCorrectKnowledgeSearchEnabled>false</spellCorrectKnowledgeSearchEnabled>
</SearchSettings>
```

With manual bruteforce I found that I can successfully deploy without this block:

```
<searchSettingsByObject> 
    <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled> 
    <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled> 
    <name>Question</name> 
    <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount> 
</searchSettingsByObject> 
<searchSettingsByObject> 
    <enhancedLookupEnabled>false</enhancedLookupEnabled> 
    <lookupAutoCompleteEnabled>false</lookupAutoCompleteEnabled> 
    <name>Reply</name> 
    <resultsPerPageCount>25</resultsPerPageCount> 
</searchSettingsByObject>
```

UPDATED: Now I can not deploy even without this nodes - I see the same error. I tried to deploy without first part of the **searchSettingsByObject** and without second part of the nodes - the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The error basically says that the object is missing. Are you sure that you have only the available objects in **Search.settings**? I had the same issue and I resolved it by simply checking if I use each **searchSettingsByObject**

For example, it might be that the problem is in the wave16__ objects or some of the standard ones that are not included. Try to figure those out and remove them. Questions and Replies were not included for me neither, so I also had to remove them from **Search.settings**.

(I know this is an old question, just leaving an answer in case if someone encounters it)

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any solution for this either, but found this:

"You have enabled Global Search and the following search settings only apply to Sidebar and Advanced Search in Portals."

So if you have Global Search enabled and do not use portals you can deploy without this file.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same problem. I haven't found a solution, but have figured out that if I take out all my custom objects and just use standard objects in the settings the deploy will work.